# React Context Mapping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I created a global context api to pull all the data from my firebase and then sending it through React Provider. But I can't seem to map through the arrays of object I am receiving.

```js
const Schedule = () => {
  const config = useContext(ConfigContext);
  return (
    <>
      <div id="ScheduleContainer" className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4">
          <img
            src={clock}
            alt="clock"
            title="clock|Icon made by flaticon author dmitri13"
          ></img>
        </div>
        {console.log(config.scheduleMap)}
        <div className="col-sm-8">
          {config.scheduleMap.map((data) => (
            <h1>{data.Event}</h1>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

where I console logged it, I can see the data. it is showing as following:

[image]

But when I try to map it I am getting the following error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference](https://www.debuggr.io/react-map-of-undefined/#wrapping-up)

When we get such an error, we are probably getting the value in an asynchronous way. We should provide an initial value for our variable or conditionally render it or both.

Following snippet may solve your problem.

```
{config.scheduleMap !== undefined ? 
    config.scheduleMap.map(data=>(
       <h1>{data.Event}</h1>))
     :
    ''
}
```

Comment: He's probably right ... you can't map the data because it isn't fetched yet ... but when you get to the console it is

Comment: Yeap, it worked. I just passed the initial variable an empty array but later it got filled